# Mi archivo js no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, html

Soy principiante en programación y al hacer un archivo de formulario mis respuestas no se ejecutan, creo que mi principal error se encuentra en los botones pero no se si mi código de js es el que está incorrecto, ya lo he comparado con antiguos proyectos similares al que estoy realizando   me gustaría saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, necesito realizar un programa de asignación de becas, con el uso de condicionantes `if` ,realmente quiero aprender pero es un problema recurrente en mis proyectos, y no se como solucionarlos.

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Becas</title>
    <link href="efectos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="Becas.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#cccccc"><center>
    <br>
    <table width="95%" cellpadding="5">
      <tr align="center" bgcolor="black">
        <td colspan="3"> <font size="6" color="white">Becas</font></td>
      </tr>
      <form name="forma">
        <tr align="center">
          <td colspan="2">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="10">
              <tr align="center">
                <td><p class="texto">PROMEDIO</p></td>
                <td><input name="Pro" type="number" size="5" class="campo"></td>
                <td><p class="texto">PUNTAJE DEL EXAMEN DE ADMISIÓN</p></td>
                <td><input name="Pun" type="number" size="5" class="campo"></td>
                                
                <td><p class="texto">INGRESOS FAMILIARES</p></td>
                <td><input name="Ing" type="number" size="5" class="campo"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
                       
            <table width="100%" bgcolor="black">
              <tr align="center">
                <td><p class="texto">Derecho a beca</td>
                <td><input name="d_b" type="text" size="5" class="campo">
              </tr>
              <tr align="center">
                <td><p class="texto">Porcentaje por promedio</td>
                <td><input name="por_pro" type="text" size="5" class="campo">
              </tr>
              <tr align="center">
                <td><p class="texto">Porcentaje por puntaje</td>
                <td><input name="por_pun" type="text" size="5" class="campo">
              </tr>
              <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
                <td><p class="texto"><font color="white">Porcentaje total</td>
                <td><input name="por_tot" type="text" size="5" class="campo">
              </tr>
            </table>
     
            <td rowspan="9" bgcolor="black"><img src="becas-diariojuridico.jpg" height="50%" width="90%"></td>
              <tr align="center">
                <td><input name="b_ejecutar" type="button" class="boton_azul"
          value="Ejecutar" onclick="calcula()">
                </td>
                <td><input name="b_reset" type="reset" class="boton_rojo"
          value="Reiniciar">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </td>
          </form>
        </table>
      </center>
    </body>
  </html>
```

```html
  function calcula() {
  Pro=parseFloat(document.forma.Pro.value);            
  Pun=parseFloat(document.forma.Pun.value);
  Ing=parseFloat(document.forma.Ing.value);
    
  d_b=(Pro)+(Pun)+(Ing);
    
  if ((Pro>=85)&&(Pun>=1300)&&(Ing<=40000)) {
    d_b= Eres candidato;
    if((Pro>=85)&&(Pro<90)) {
      por_pro= 20;
    }
    
    if ((Pro>=90)&&(Pro<95)) {
      por_pro=30;
    }
    
    if (Pro<95) {
      por_pro=40;
    }
    
    if((Pun>=1300)&&(Pun<=1399)) {
      por_pro= 10;
    }
    
    if ((Pun>=1400)&&(Pun<=1599)) {
      por_pro=15;
    }
    
    if (Pun<1600) {
      por_pro=20;
    }
    por_tot=(por_pro+por_pun);
  } else {
    d_b= NO eres candidato;
  }
  document.forma.d_b.text=d_b;
  document.forma.por_pro.value=por_pro;
  document.forma.por_pun.value=por_pun;
  document.forma.por_tot.value=por_tot;
}
```

Comment: cuando abres la consola del navegador arroja algun error?

Comment: A simple vista tienes varios errores: le estas asignando un `string` a la variable `d_b` sin las comillas, la variable `por_tot` la tienes local dentro del primer `if`, pero la estas llamando fuera y eso te dará error. Y lo otro es que cada variable es recomendable, sino obligatorio especificar si es `let` (var) o `const`

Answer (score 1):

Voy a focalizar mi respuesta sobre la pregunta "Mi archivo js no se ejecuta". Creo que es importante tener resuelto el orden y carga de recursos cuando se trabaja en un proyecto que utiliza HTML y JS.

Generalmente cuando empiezas un nuevo proyecto que utiliza JavaScript conviene entender cómo funciona la carga de recursos desde la página HTML que estas usando.

Por ejemplo, todo lo que está puesto en el `<head>` se va a cargar antes del contenido HTML ubicado en el `<body>` (la excepción son los scripts [`async` / `defer`](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer)). Esto quiere decir que si intentas realizar una operación sobre un elemento que aún no ha sido cargado, vas a recibir un error. Por ejemplo:

Contenido de `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="main-title">Hola</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Contenido de `app.js`:

```
document.getElementById('main-title').innerText = 'Como estas?'
```

Si procedemos a cargar la pagina, la misma devuelve un error:
[image: output consola]

El error se produce porque el intérprete JavaScript intenta encontrar un elemento en el DOM que aún no está presente.

Para evitar este tipo de problemas, siempre conviene cargar los scripts una vez que los elementos del `<body>` han finalizado su carga.

Para lograr esto se coloca los `<script>` tags antes de la etiqueta `</body>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="main-title">Hola</h1>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Una vez hecho esto, puedes estar seguro de que el script de JavaScript está cargando de forma correcta. El paso siguiente sería realizar un debugging del código mismo e iterar hasta que los errores y bugs estén resueltos.